# Face reflect problem with perfume bottle

Tags: objects, faces, lighting, reflection

[image]
I try to make a perfume bottle. I did check every vertex from top and side perspective, everything was lined up straight in its place. Why the light reflects still come out like this?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It looks like you have a flipped normal. Select the whole mesh in edit mode, then select `Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside`

Comment: moonboots - Ok, here it is https://pasteall.org/blend/2a99090ed81f4a718fc4c17fa808e25b

Comment: Ok, It was flipped. Thank you Christopher Bennett and moonboots.

Comment: Ok, It was flipped. Thank you Christopher Bennett and moonboots.